# Storing objects/variables outside of volatile memory

Tags: json, cordova, typescript, mobile, storage

**OVERVIEW**

I don’t have a lot of experience programming, but I’m working on a hybrid mobile app using Cordova. This app is going to have a large amount of static (not changing) data. Some of this data will be referenced about once every minute, complete some simple operations based on that reference, and that will determine which object will be referenced in the next iteration of the loop.

From what I understand all that an object or variable is, is a reserved space within memory identified using a name. Which in hardware terms is synonyms with volatile storage or RAM. Because I will be working with mobile devices I am afraid that the massive amounts of objects I predict I will be working with (say close to 10,000), will max out the devices memory pretty fast.

My initial thought is to store this collection of static data in local storage instead of declaring these objects within the code itself. Then I would reference that file for the data when needed with each iteration of my loop, which processes once every minute. I don’t have experience with JSON but from what I know about it, this seems like it could be a good option.

**BREAKDOWN**

•   I’m using typescript and Cordova.

•   I will possibly be working with 10s of thousands of static objects.

•   These objects will all be using one of a few interfaces as an outline.

•   A few of these objects will be referenced for some information about once every minute.

•   That information will be used to perform very simple operations.

•   The Id of the object that was referenced may need to be saved permanently for future use.

•   Those operations will determine what objects need to be referenced in the next iteration.

**QUESTION(S)**

So, my question is this.  Am I correct in my understanding of how objects are stored? If so, will this number of objects be enough to max out a mobile devices RAM? Is my thought of storing all the static information in something like a JSON file and then referencing the individual objects in that file as needed plausible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite correct.  Modern operating systems don't always map the application's memory to the hardware RAM.

Let's say you have a phone that only has 256MB of total RAM, but your application ends up loading 128MB of data into memory.  Does that mean you can only use one more application that can load 128MB of memory?  What about the OS itself using memory? The answer is that, the OS will move some of the data from the primary memory (e.g. RAM), into secondary storage (e.g. solid-state drive,) making room for your app and other apps to do their work as needed.  If the data that was moved out of the RAM is needed again, the OS can move it back into the RAM from the SSD. This is called [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging), and it's one of the many different pieces that make up the operating system's memory management.  Most of it is done without your application code having to be aware of it.

Of course, even though the OS does a pretty great job of making memory available to your application, you still want to write code that's still memory efficient. Specially on mobile phones.

For your specific example, your suggestion of storing the static data in local storage is a good start. But it has some drawbacks as well that you should be aware; and some questions you should answer.

- Can you divide up the data so that you can load only the portion you need at a time?  Or do you need to have all of it loaded anyway?
- Can you store your data in a more compressed data structure? (see for example [Tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie))
- How frequently will you be loading the data from local storage?
- Will loading the data from local storage take too long (e.g. if your loop does a thousand iterations, and during each iteration loads a lot of static data from the disk, it might end up being really slow).

Good luck!